# Python Поиск и удаление пар значений из списка

Tags: python, алгоритм, pandas, numpy

Есть список чисел в датафрейме. Из этого списка нужно найти пары чисел `a` и `b`, такие чтобы `a == -b`. Если такие пары есть их нужно дропнуть.

Вопрос собственно в том, **как это сделать максимально эффективно?**

### Условия

- `a == -b`
- Необходимо найти и удалить все пары.
- Числа удаляются только папарно.
- Числа корорые уже входят в пару не могут быть частью другой пары. Т.е. для числа `с` нужно искать другое `d` даже если `с == -b` или `с == -a`
- Все равно что происходит с нулями `0 == -0`. Можно удалить или оставить, главное чтобы работало быстрее.
- Не обязательно, но было бы лучше, если бы растояние по индексу, между парой, было минимальным.
- Порядок чисел не должен поменятся после удаления. Нужно оставить исходные индексы датафрейма.

### Текущая реализация

```
def drop_paired(data:pd.DataFrame, target_column:str):
    result = data.copy()
    result['index'] = result.index
    # Сортируем значения без учета знака
    result = result.sort_values([target_column, 'index'], key=abs)
    result['drop'] = False

    value_a = index_a = np.nan
    i = start_i = 0
    while i < len(result):
        row = result.iloc[i]
        
        # Проверяем не использовано это число в качестве какой либо пары
        if(~row['drop']):
            # Если значение и индекс первого числа в паре (a) не определены, задаем новые
            if(index_a is np.nan):
                value_a = row[target_column]
                index_a = row['index']
                start_i = i

            # Если нашли b == -a, ставим пометку на удаление и опустошаем значение и индекс первого числа в паре
            elif(row[target_column] == -value_a):
                result.loc[row['index'], 'drop'] = True
                result.loc[index_a, 'drop'] = True
                value_a = index_a = np.nan
                
                # Возвращаемся назад для поисков другой пары среди этих же значений
                i = start_i
                continue

            # Если есть а с более "старшим" индексом, возьмём его, чтобы расстояние между a и b было минимальным
            elif(row[target_column] == value_a):
                index_a = row['index']

            # Если числа не равны по модулю, задаем новые
            else:
                value_a = row[target_column]
                index_a = row['index']
                start_i = i
        
        i += 1
            
    result = result[~result['drop']].sort_index()   
    return result[list(data)]
```

### Результат работы

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-6, 11, 20))

print("До дропа")
display(df.value_counts())
display(df)
print("\n--------------\nПосле дропа")
display(drop_paired(df, 0).value_counts())
drop_paired(df, 0)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Итого

Алгоритм работает, но меня смущает гавнокодовость данного решения. Как сделать лучше?

Comment: Отличная задача! Особенно вопрос выделения близких пар.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посоветовали в другом месте следующее

```
def drop_paired2(data:pd.DataFrame, by:str):
    sort_values = data[by].sort_values()
    abs_values = sort_values.abs()
    c1 = sort_values.groupby(abs_values).transform(pd.Series.cumsum) > 0
    c2 = sort_values[::-1].groupby(abs_values).transform(pd.Series.cumsum) < 0
    
    return data[c1 | c2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну, для обычного списка я не вижу тут чего-то сложного.

```
data = [6,9,-6,-3,-3,1,3,-2,0,6,-5,0,1,8,-1,7,2,3,10,-1]
i = 0
while i < len(data):
    try:
        i_pair = data.index(-data[i], i+1)   # ищем антипода для текущего элемента (начиная со следующего)
        del data[i_pair]                     # удаляем антипода
        del data[i]                          # удаляем сам элемент
    except ValueError :                      # если антипода не нашли
        i += 1                               # переходим к следующему элементу
print(data)
```

```
>>> [9, 6, -5, 8, 7, 10]
```

Comment: Когда я писал (уже удалил) что мне не важно будет ли это пандас или нет, я думал что смогу в 2 счета перенести это все туда. Не смог)

Answer (score 0):

решение через рекурсивную функцию:

```
data = [6,9,-6,-3,-3,1,3,-2,0,6,-5,0,1,8,-1,7,2,3,10,-1]

def f(x):
    if not x: return []
    if -x[0] not in x[1:]: return [x.pop(0)] + f(x)
    del x[x.index(-x.pop(0))]
    return f(x)

f(data)  # [9, 6, -5, 8, 7, 10]
```